# Django: reverse list of many to many relationship?

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I have two simple models in models.py: Service and Host. Host.services has a m2m relationship with Service.
In other words, a host has several services and one service can reside on multiple hosts; a basic m2m.

**models.py**

```
class Service(models.Model):
        servicename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.servicename
        class Admin:
                pass

class Host(models.Model):
        #...
        hostname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
        #...

        def service(self):
                return "\n".join([s.servicename for s in self.services.all()])

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.hostname

        class Admin:
                pass
```

How do I get a one-to-many output in the admin interface, with the class 'Service' as basis (a reverse many-to-many?).

Do I need to use '_set.all()' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `related_name` on the services:

```
services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, related_name='hosts')
```

and then do

```
service.hosts.all()
```

to get the hosts for a service.

Comment: Do i put this:

service.hosts.all()

within 'class Host'?

Comment: No. If you have a `Host` instance `host` and you want to find its services, you'd do `host.services.all()`. Similarly, if you have a `Service` instance `service` and you want to find its hosts, you do `service.hosts.all()`. Here, `service` is a particular `Service` instance you're interested in at any particular time.

Comment: This would typically go into code for a view (e.g. to display the hosts for a service when viewing the service information)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    servicename = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def hostname(self):
            return "\n".join([s.hostname for s in self.hosts_services.all()])

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.servicename

class Host(models.Model):
    #...
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, related_name='hosts_services')
    #...
```