# Django: Iterating over a reversed many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have created a many-to-many relationship between my User model and my Projects model, and I want to list all the projects a specific user is part of on the user's profile page.

My **models** are:

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Prosjekter(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, verbose_name="Project participants")
    ...
```

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) states that:

> Reverse m2m queries are supported (i.e., starting at the table that doesn’t have a ManyToManyField):
>
> `>>> Publication.objects.filter(article__id=1)`
>
> `<QuerySet [<Publication: The Python Journal>]>`

I am able to print the QuerySet of a *specific* user by typing (here illustrated with the user whose primary key is 2):

```
class UserDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/user_detail.html'
    results = Prosjekter.objects.filter(users__pk=2),
    print(results)
```

This will return:

```
(<QuerySet [<Prosjekter: Project 1>, <Prosjekter: Project two>, <Prosjekter: Project third>]>,)
```

However, as you can see, I am only calling the user whose primary key is **2**. Instead, I want to create a view that can be used in the general sense. Specifically, that I can see:

- all user 1's projects on http://.../users/1/
- all user 2's projects on http://.../users/2/
- and so on

I am new to Python and Django and have trouble creating this view. Among many other attempts, I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421820/django-reverse-list-of-many-to-many-relationship) suggestion without success. Therefore, can you please help me with the following?

1. Can you update my **UserDetailView** code so that it works for all users?
2. Can you show me the code that I must implement on the **/user_detail.html** page (if I have understood it correctly, it should be a for loop that iterates through all the projects in the *Prosjekter* model and lists only those in which the specific user is a part of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `DetailView` wrong:

```
class UserDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/user_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['results'] = Prosjekter.objects.filter(users=self.get_object())
        return ctx
```

If you want more context variables, add them this way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx.update({
        'results': Prosjekter.objects.filter(users=self.get_object()),
        'foo': 'bar',
        'spam': 'ham',
    })
    return ctx
```

Comment: bakatrouble:   thank you for a quick reply. May I ask you to post the template tag code I need in my user_detail.html file as well? Edit: never  mind, I got it to work: {% for prosjekter  in results  %}  {{ prosjekter.id }} {% endfor %}. Thank you for helping me out – I've been sitting with this for hours!

Comment: `{% for result in results %}{{ result.pk }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: bakatrouble:   Can you help me out with one more thing? I did not mention it in this post, but I actually have _three_ many-to-many relationships between the User model and the Projects model: 1) one m2m field in Prosjekter is named **responsiblefordata**, 2) another field in Prosjekter is named **users** (which you helped me out with already), and 3) the third field in prosjekter is named **contactperson**. I have tried to use multiple **def get_context_data** and I tried merging them into one def, switching out _ctx_ and _results_ with other names both times. It will only show one of them.

Comment: Updated the answer